# Is there an easy way to update a backup drive?

Tags: backup

I'm using ubuntu. I have an external drive and a backup of it. Is there any easy way to update the backup with changes made to the original drive? Essentially, when I add or remove or move files in the original, is there some utility by which I can update the backup to reflect these changes without having to perform the same actions on the backup drive? Something that will look at the first drive and just update the differences onto the backup?

Comment: Please note that that's not a proper backup - you have only the most recent copy. What if you'll realize you've deleted an important file 2 months ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of these two tools to allows files to be kept in sync with each other.

[Unison](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Unison)

> Unison is a GUI and terminal-based tool which allows files and
> directories to be kept in sync with each other, between different
> local directories and drives or on a network, which could be on
> different operating systems.

[FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/)

> FreeFileSync is a folder comparison and synchronization software that
> creates and manages backup copies of all your important files. Instead
> of copying every file every time, FreeFileSync determines the
> differences between a source and a target folder and transfers only
> the minimum amount of data needed.

Comment: Thanks Mico! Unison is perfect for my purposes.